# insert select from on duplicate key ignore postgres

Tags: postgresql, on-duplicate-key, insert-select

I've read from this source that you can do an insert on dupcliate key ignore in postgres, but I cannot seem to get this to work for a select from:

[link](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAM3SWZRg4VcLCKprVEyuLHoXwUefuiz1-P69YLye8qktZb_%3DUQ@mail.gmail.com)

What I've seen you can do is:

```
insert into tab(id, val) values(1, 'nosert'), (2,
'nosert'), (3, 'nosert') on duplicate key ignore returning id;
```

Why can't I do something like this?

```
insert into table_one (field_one, field_two) select field_one, field_two from table_two on duplicate key ignore returning field_one;
```

I'm being told that I have syntax error near duplicate, but the query before then runs fine (although it colides on a duplicate index) and the rest of the query just adds the `on duplicate key ignore returning field_one`.

Is this not possible with `select from`?

Answer (score 10):

Was able to resolve with `on conflict do nothing` for 9.5

```
insert into table_one (field_one, field_two) 
select field_one, field_two from table_two 
on conflict do nothing;
```